# Get all the Inputs in a list or a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to add more than one Product's Name and their prices in a single nested list or single dictionary.
(The respective function in the following code is `def add_screen(self)`).

But I am not able find a way to do so.

**In main.py --> class AddScreen(Screen) --> def add_screen(self) --> 'pdt' and 'amt'**

I want to make a nested list or a dictionary of `pdt` and `amt` from the User input whenever the user clicks the `Add More` Button.

***main.py***

```
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    from gui_elements import screen_helper


    class NameScreen(Screen):
        c_name = ObjectProperty(None)

        def c_name_p(self):
            customer = self.c_name.text


    class AddScreen(Screen):
        p_name = ObjectProperty(None)
        amnt = ObjectProperty(None)

        def add_screen(self):
            pdt = self.p_name.text
            amt = self.amnt.text

            self.p_name.text = ''
            self.amnt.text = ''


    # Create the screen manager
    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(NameScreen(name='menu'))
    sm.add_widget(AddScreen(name='profile'))


    class DukanApp(MDApp):

        def build(self):
            screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
            return screen


    DukanApp().run()
```

***gui_elements.py***

```
    screen_helper = """
    ScreenManager:
        NameScreen:
        AddScreen:

    <NameScreen>:
        id: name_screen
        c_name: c_name
        name: 'menu'
        MDTextField:
            id: c_name
            hint_text: "Enter the Customer's Name"
            helper_text: 'Ex- Mrinmoy Sarkar'
            helper_text_mode: 'persistent'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 300
            icon_right: 'account'
        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: 'Next'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.4}
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'add'
            on_press: root.c_name_p()

    <AddScreen>:
        id: add_screen
        p_name: p_name
        amnt: amnt
        name: 'add'
        MDTextField:
            id: p_name
            hint_text: "Name of the Product"
            helper_text: 'Ex- T-Shirt , Jeans , etc.'
            helper_text_mode: 'persistent'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.3,'center_y':0.5}
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 300
        MDTextField:
            id: amnt
            hint_text: "Cost of The Product"
            helper_text: 'Ex- 1200 , 1000 , etc.'
            helper_text_mode: 'persistent'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.7,'center_y':0.5}
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: 'Continue'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.6365,'center_y':0.4}
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'add'
            on_press: root.add_screen()
        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: 'Add More'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.7755,'center_y':0.4}
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'add'
            on_press: root.add_screen()
    """
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create the dictionary. Here, I chose to do that in your `App` class:

```
class DukanApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.products = {}   # create the products dictionary
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen
```

Then add items to that dictionary in the `add_screen()` method:

```
def add_screen(self):
    pdt = self.p_name.text
    amt = self.amnt.text

    # get a reference to the products dictionary
    products = MDApp.get_running_app().products
    # add this product to the dictionary
    products[pdt] = amt

    print('products:', products)

    self.p_name.text = ''
    self.amnt.text = ''
```

Comment: It works . Thank You very much for your support.

Comment: Sir , I am still learning kivy . So I would like to know the best method and resources to learn kivy?